# Android: card emulation - read ndef message with PN532 nfc module

Tags: android, tags, nfc, ndef, hce

I have an LG D320n Android phone, elechouse's PN532 nfc module and Stollmann's NFCPlayer with which I can read NFC tags properly.

I tested a sample from here: https://github.com/grundid/host-card-emulation-sample

It works fine, when I read one Android device as tag with another Android device as reader. But I can not read the Android device as tag with PN532 reader through NFCPlayer. I want reader to read an NDEF message from the Android device acting as a tag, but NFCPlayer doesn't even recognise the Android device. I think I have to write some modifications on the Android side but I can't figure it out what to do. I think I don't have enough knowlege about how NFC communication and HCE work, even though I read this: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html

I would really appreciate any guideline that could help me understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [grundid example app](https://github.com/grundid/host-card-emulation-sample) should be discovered by NFCPlayer as a "legacy tag" (tab "R/W: Legacy") as it does not implement the NDEF abstraction layer. On that tab, you can exchange PDUs (APDUs in the case of HCE) with the emulated smartcard. A valid APDU for the example app would be

```
00 A4 04 00 07 F0010203040506 00
```

You can send this APDU by typing it into the PDU field and clicking on the "Exch. PDU" button. Note that the grundid HCE app does not even implement ISO/IEC 7816-4 response APDUs. Hence, you may run into troubles with some contactless smartcard readers.

If you want your emulated smartcard to be discoverabe by NFCPlayer as NFC Forum Type 4 tag containing an NDEF message (tab "R/W: NDEF"), you would need to implement the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag Operation specification (as defined by the [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum.org/). This specification defines how data must be stored on an (emulated) ISO/IEC 14443-4 smartcard to be interpreted as NDEF tag. As a starting point you could use this [NDEF on HCE example app](https://github.com/hirokuma/HceSample) (though, the quality and reliability of that code is questionable). This example implements the smartcard filesystem for storing NDEF data.

Comment: I am sorry for such late response. I had some other projects which had to be done first. Your answer helped me a lot. thanks! (I figured it out that i don't need ndef messages so I didn't test this part). Thanks a lot!

Comment: hi, I have another question. It is working smoothly with OnePluse One with CM. in logcat I have those outputs:
07-08 10:30:03.445   1468-26171/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::stackCallback: event=0x18
07-08 10:30:03.450   1468-26171/? D/HostEmulationManager﹕ notifyHostEmulationActivated
07-08 10:30:03.452   1468-26171/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::stackCallback: event=0x17
07-08 10:30:03.452   1468-26171/? D/BrcmNfcJni﹕ RoutingManager::stackCallback: NFA_CE_DATA_EVT; stat=0x0; h=0x301; data len=13

Comment: and NFCPlayer finds my android device as ISO 14443-A card with 1234 ID and then I can exch. PDU. 
but with another device (LG d320n) it is not working... NFCPlayer does not recognise it and RoutingManager::stackCallback: event=0x18 or notifyHostEmulationActivated is not called as I could see it in logcat. why is that? Interesting is that oneplus device is recogniseing LG with grundid app (receiver mode). Thanks in advance!